# cassandra query on map in select clause

Tags: cassandra-2.0, cql3

i am new to cassandra and i am trying to read a row from database which contains values

### siteId | country | someMap

1       |     US  | {a:b, x:z}

---

2       |     PR  | {a:b, x:z}

I have also created an index on table using create index on columnfamily(keys(someMap));

but still when i query as select * from table where siteId=1 and someMap contains key 'a'

it returns an entiremap as

---

1       |     US  | {a:b, x:z}

Can somebody help me on what should i do to get the value as

1       |     US  | {a:b}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not: even if internally each entry of a `Map|List|Set` is stored as a column you can only retrieve the whole collection but not part of it. You are not asking cassandra give me the entry of the map containing X, but the row whom map contains X.

HTH,
Carlo

Comment: so that means there is no way we can get a row where the map contains specific key???

Comment: You can get a row where a map contains a specific value but you can't retrieve a subset of values from the map. As you've seen in your test the retrieved map is always complete.